# Access denied error when connecting to remote MySQL server using Perl DBD-mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I attempt to connect to a remote MySQL server with Perl DBD-mysql module. The client is under Windows, so before connecting with Perl, I did some tests with Windos cmd line:

```
mysql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -u root -p database -P 3306
```

And it returned `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'my-pc-name'`. I did some research on the Internet and found running `grant all privileges on *.* to root@"%" identified by "password"` on the server side could sovle this problem. Then I succeeded in connecting to the server.

However, there's still such access problem when connecting using Perl DBD-mysql module. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database@xx.xx.xx.xx', 'root', 'password'
                   ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

It reported:

```
DBI connect('database@xx.xx.xx.xx','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Could you please give some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [the DBI CPAN doc page](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm), I found two alternatives of `$data_source` for `DBI->connect`. In contrast of my first attempt, the more detailed one could succeed in connecting to MySQL server. It said:

```
Examples of $data_source values are:

  dbi:DriverName:database_name
  dbi:DriverName:database_name@hostname:port
  dbi:DriverName:database=database_name;host=hostname;port=port
```

Although the second one seems not working for me, I turned to the third one, namely

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:dbname=database;host=xx.xx.xx.xx','root', 'password'
                   ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

which worked like a charm.